# evento .change de jQuery no actualiza en iPhone

Tags: php, jquery

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]tengo 3 select de html que son dinámicos(se rellenan con base de datos, uno depende de otro, con jQuery mando a realizar la consulta para que cambie la información del siguiente select hasta ahi todo funciona bien el problema que al hacer la consulta con un iPhone el primer select hace bien por que tiene que seleccionar forzosamente una opción al seleccionarla aparecen las opciones en el segundo select pero queda la opción del iPhone habilitada de poder regresar al primer select y si cambia la opción y no le da el botón "listo del iPhone" no se actualiza la info del segundo select no se si el evento .change del jQuery tenga que cambiarlo por otro

Comment: Cuando dices que no le da al botón de "listo", ¿te refieres a que pulsa fuera del select y desaparecen las opciones? En este caso creo que el comportamiento de iPhone es no modificar el valor del select

Comment: en realidad todo funciona bien si pulsa listo de la opción del iPhone se cargan el siguiente select, si pulsa afuera también lo carga, donde no carga es si esta en en el segundo select y regresa con las flechas del iPhone al primer select y ahi vuele a seleccionar otra opción y nuevamente con las flechitas se cambia al segundo select ahi no se refresca el segundo select se queda con las opciones anteriores digamos que las flechitas del iPhone no reconoce el evento change ni el focus out ni el click no se que evento colocar para que reconozca ese evento de las flechitas del iPhone

Comment: no le entiendo mucho al ingles y la traducción no es muy buena pero lo mas que he encontrado fue esto https://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/09/click_event_del.html

Answer (score 0):

El evento change en iphone suele dar errores, una solución alternativa es utilizar el método `delegate`:

```
$("#elemento").delegate('select', "change", function(){
  alert('hello');
});
```

Te dejo también la documentación de [delegate()](https://api.jquery.com/delegate/#delegate-selector-eventType-handler).

Si ves que esto no lo soluciona, añade a la pregunta tu código y la version de jquery que utilizas para que te podamos ayudar mejor.

Un saludo!